# Fourier Transform of Voltage Readings

Tags: fourier, fft, frequency-domain

I am working on developing a Fourier transform for voltage readings. The goal is to determine voltages at different frequencies (frequency domain). I am taking readings at **100Hz** and am measuring both the Average and TRMS voltages over time (time domain). **For this question, I am only working with the "avg" data.**

I have been utilizing the Fourier Analysis within Excel. I then utilize the =IMABS() function for each of the FFT (avg) values and divide by the amount of sample taken, 512 samples (i.e. **=IMABS(*FFT Value*)/512**). I then plot the results against the frequency (Hz).

Below is a table of example data. *Apologies for the long list but the Fourier function in Excel only works with certain number of samples (i.e. 2, 4, 8,...256, 512, etc)*

Attached is an image of the graph obtained when I graph just the *avg* values with respect to frequency.[image]

This is a new area for me so I'm hoping to get some insight, guidance, and make sure that I'm not overlooking something. I am also aware of the **Nyquist theorem** and am therefore not confident with any graphed voltages above 50Hz.

| Time (sec.) | Voltage (avg) | Counter | Freq. (Hz) | FFT (avg) | Amplitude (avg) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.0000 | -0.464 | 0 | 0 | -229.039 | 0.447341797 |
| 0.0100 | -0.521 | 1 | 0.195694716 | 10.1322200016599+1.645257812029i | 0.020048688 |
| 0.0200 | -0.401 | 2 | 0.391389432 | 9.65075248625337+2.76041332464675i | 0.019605027 |
| 0.0300 | -0.512 | 3 | 0.587084149 | 9.15268494359245+4.03087189358114i | 0.019533161 |
| 0.0400 | -0.44 | 4 | 0.782778865 | 8.25681453333612+5.27235979553822i | 0.019133924 |
| 0.0500 | -0.467 | 5 | 0.978473581 | 7.21324666201885+6.22104757994938i | 0.018604206 |
| 0.0600 | -0.519 | 6 | 1.174168297 | 6.07955964718428+6.93019294202941i | 0.018005717 |
| 0.0700 | -0.405 | 7 | 1.369863014 | 4.83143342629608+7.37208937173917i | 0.017215271 |
| 0.0800 | -0.512 | 8 | 1.56555773 | 3.59291030204946+7.57742009618472i | 0.016379058 |
| 0.0900 | -0.433 | 9 | 1.761252446 | 2.37433650922022+7.59420275947096i | 0.015540468 |
| 0.1000 | -0.47 | 10 | 1.956947162 | 1.15340023381173+7.33229089156102i | 0.01449698 |
| 0.1100 | -0.52 | 11 | 2.152641879 | 0.120712139467973+6.91156950591859i | 0.013501218 |
| 0.1200 | -0.405 | 12 | 2.348336595 | -0.818067214278053+6.29386664644949i | 0.012396112 |
| 0.1300 | -0.516 | 13 | 2.544031311 | -1.51563676527916+5.57318532827966i | 0.011280468 |
| 0.1400 | -0.427 | 14 | 2.739726027 | -2.03711466482809+4.77308097389415i | 0.010135973 |
| 0.1500 | -0.473 | 15 | 2.935420744 | -2.37469986904867+3.92829794114827i | 0.008965402 |
| 0.1600 | -0.516 | 16 | 3.13111546 | -2.51483612661896+3.05848270837768i | 0.007733664 |
| 0.1700 | -0.408 | 17 | 3.326810176 | -2.48721204893401+2.29485333429039i | 0.006609698 |
| 0.1800 | -0.522 | 18 | 3.522504892 | -2.31824822704003+1.56731883117559i | 0.005465527 |
| 0.1900 | -0.42 | 19 | 3.718199609 | -1.9729997846832+0.960300569731039i | 0.004285721 |
| 0.2000 | -0.478 | 20 | 3.913894325 | -1.54872675438711+0.515919754555665i | 0.00318828 |
| 0.2100 | -0.512 | 21 | 4.109589041 | -1.08489578685385+0.185004760673414i | 0.002149525 |
| 0.2200 | -0.407 | 22 | 4.305283757 | -0.600187211577808+3.42696351333572E-002i | 0.00117415 |
| 0.2300 | -0.522 | 23 | 4.500978474 | -0.141753016604165-1.5540399065834E-002i | 0.00027852 |
| 0.2400 | -0.416 | 24 | 4.69667319 | 0.290088046498194+5.29223345462406E-002i | 0.00057593 |
| 0.2500 | -0.483 | 25 | 4.892367906 | 0.637581694745883+0.270631882678479i | 0.001352815 |
| 0.2600 | -0.509 | 26 | 5.088062622 | 0.913697152631281+0.525795104052738i | 0.002058952 |
| 0.2700 | -0.408 | 27 | 5.283757339 | 1.07948700704762+0.877326776329355i | 0.002716877 |
| 0.2800 | -0.523 | 28 | 5.479452055 | 1.09431775695688+1.18413901721967i | 0.003149148 |
| 0.2900 | -0.414 | 29 | 5.675146771 | 1.04197490942795+1.49153138884348i | 0.003553602 |
| 0.3000 | -0.485 | 30 | 5.870841487 | 0.930424506303088+1.75894591194859i | 0.003886464 |
| 0.3100 | -0.507 | 31 | 6.066536204 | 0.700274984853021+1.98375634269125i | 0.004108845 |
| 0.3200 | -0.413 | 32 | 6.26223092 | 0.427036374279053+2.18627755520587i | 0.004350767 |
| 0.3300 | -0.522 | 33 | 6.457925636 | 0.114825551542406+2.30452647107527i | 0.004506612 |
| 0.3400 | -0.41 | 34 | 6.653620352 | -0.251612518345346+2.25525310623467i | 0.00443212 |
| 0.3500 | -0.489 | 35 | 6.849315068 | -0.485424402852134+2.06281583436469i | 0.004138988 |
| 0.3600 | -0.504 | 36 | 7.045009785 | -0.786799114041862+1.99599329978933i | 0.004190371 |
| 0.3700 | -0.417 | 37 | 7.240704501 | -0.980003621162694+1.72068507267303i | 0.003867564 |
| 0.3800 | -0.52 | 38 | 7.436399217 | -1.13255633499022+1.50728840390684i | 0.003682354 |
| 0.3900 | -0.405 | 39 | 7.632093933 | -1.21522126871698+1.18661576554237i | 0.003317335 |
| 0.4000 | -0.488 | 40 | 7.82778865 | -1.17816222637269+0.911135070016272i | 0.002908933 |
| 0.4100 | -0.506 | 41 | 8.023483366 | -1.16058223145583+0.593483129168018i | 0.002545944 |
| 0.4200 | -0.422 | 42 | 8.219178082 | -0.977497440390513+0.338823108580408i | 0.002020614 |
| 0.4300 | -0.523 | 43 | 8.414872798 | -0.815688606400097+0.173771044887206i | 0.001628893 |
| 0.4400 | -0.407 | 44 | 8.610567515 | -0.602590140658854+4.03168948966772E-002i | 0.001179565 |
| 0.4500 | -0.481 | 45 | 8.806262231 | -0.336934811223527-1.93959361379846E-002i | 0.000659165 |
| 0.4600 | -0.501 | 46 | 9.001956947 | -0.136169857776244-7.50361244454022E-003i | 0.00026636 |
| 0.4700 | -0.426 | 47 | 9.197651663 | 6.02639217652264E-002+1.85540060806169E-002i | 0.000123155 |
| 0.4800 | -0.526 | 48 | 9.39334638 | 0.282481666820933+0.121647899267673i | 0.000600706 |
| 0.4900 | -0.402 | 49 | 9.589041096 | 0.413875144645062+0.323198016919613i | 0.001025622 |
| 0.5000 | -0.488 | 50 | 9.784735812 | 0.46382645002229+0.468359872354553i | 0.001287428 |
| 0.5100 | -0.494 | 51 | 9.980430528 | 0.512458090741133+0.692113347663311i | 0.001681996 |
| 0.5200 | -0.427 | 52 | 10.17612524 | 0.464175821857294+0.885410206930413i | 0.001952549 |
| 0.5300 | -0.527 | 53 | 10.37181996 | 0.392704495708325+1.00365121409194i | 0.002104969 |
| 0.5400 | -0.4 | 54 | 10.56751468 | 0.302381753466691+1.19598555887027i | 0.002409412 |
| 0.5500 | -0.488 | 55 | 10.76320939 | 9.41359784704656E-002+1.28098489205329i | 0.00250867 |
| 0.5600 | -0.492 | 56 | 10.95890411 | -5.37145520510952E-002+1.33217729659522i | 0.002604023 |
| 0.5700 | -0.429 | 57 | 11.15459883 | -0.284153335815369+1.33831690461504i | 0.002672169 |
| 0.5800 | -0.526 | 58 | 11.35029354 | -0.479510056494082+1.23706803934805i | 0.00259131 |
| 0.5900 | -0.401 | 59 | 11.54598826 | -0.588508197996208+1.14420786763055i | 0.002513053 |
| 0.6000 | -0.49 | 60 | 11.74168297 | -0.750933338056818+1.02322392513199i | 0.002478921 |
| 0.6100 | -0.485 | 61 | 11.93737769 | -0.845420982463707+0.850399701728216i | 0.002342054 |
| 0.6200 | -0.436 | 62 | 12.13307241 | -0.872099113161632+0.688965118144201i | 0.002170721 |
| 0.6300 | -0.526 | 63 | 12.32876712 | -0.867696056991852+0.510911890146492i | 0.001966679 |
| 0.6400 | -0.394 | 64 | 12.52446184 | -0.846118361750733+0.312787409309037i | 0.001761879 |
| 0.6500 | -0.494 | 65 | 12.72015656 | -0.700763258734886+0.223785630558508i | 0.001436774 |
| 0.6600 | -0.482 | 66 | 12.91585127 | -0.594363584722293+4.34415449685877E-002i | 0.001163963 |
| 0.6700 | -0.441 | 67 | 13.11154599 | -0.443418702758577-2.81778533350083E-002i | 0.000867799 |
| 0.6800 | -0.526 | 68 | 13.3072407 | -0.274173268602233-7.75294764816895E-002i | 0.000556493 |
| 0.6900 | -0.393 | 69 | 13.50293542 | -9.19087189277066E-002-3.67290016722993E-002i | 0.000193312 |
| 0.7000 | -0.494 | 70 | 13.69863014 | 8.35034877995999E-002-2.88689128021349E-002i | 0.000172564 |
| 0.7100 | -0.478 | 71 | 13.89432485 | 0.14501529433385+0.119597410589135i | 0.00036713 |
| 0.7200 | -0.445 | 72 | 14.09001957 | 0.228733084556724+0.235312617319269i | 0.000640943 |
| 0.7300 | -0.525 | 73 | 14.28571429 | 0.240052412637727+0.373773413956849i | 0.000867618 |
| 0.7400 | -0.398 | 74 | 14.481409 | 0.255815600480613+0.462556756670193i | 0.001032389 |
| 0.7500 | -0.49 | 75 | 14.67710372 | 0.251409383369858+0.627395398931579i | 0.001320104 |
| 0.7600 | -0.47 | 76 | 14.87279843 | 0.162566798954433+0.725722332958638i | 0.001452554 |
| 0.7700 | -0.45 | 77 | 15.06849315 | 0.104515512093105+0.834013887905941i | 0.001641674 |
| 0.7800 | -0.528 | 78 | 15.26418787 | -2.0872726813188E-002+0.934920308584918i | 0.001826471 |
| 0.7900 | -0.399 | 79 | 15.45988258 | -0.228172660942765+0.927106694266334i | 0.001864789 |
| 0.8000 | -0.495 | 80 | 15.6555773 | -0.297715370895055+0.882984934377287i | 0.00181997 |
| 0.8100 | -0.464 | 81 | 15.85127202 | -0.459154214398574+0.858790262541157i | 0.00190201 |
| 0.8200 | -0.454 | 82 | 16.04696673 | -0.531759684345087+0.71193743420169i | 0.001735562 |
| 0.8300 | -0.528 | 83 | 16.24266145 | -0.582897694831826+0.648138862991088i | 0.001702531 |
| 0.8400 | -0.401 | 84 | 16.43835616 | -0.691101659464284+0.514854162590408i | 0.0016832 |
| 0.8500 | -0.503 | 85 | 16.63405088 | -0.781199731191186+9.11054335093847E-002i | 0.001536122 |
| 0.8600 | -0.454 | 86 | 16.8297456 | -0.65640093657412+0.436884039324661i | 0.001540036 |
| 0.8700 | -0.456 | 87 | 17.02544031 | -0.711289955077337+0.215317467471172i | 0.001451495 |
| 0.8800 | -0.522 | 88 | 17.22113503 | -0.523077156180344+6.50100020610644E-002i | 0.001029495 |
| 0.8900 | -0.404 | 89 | 17.41682975 | -0.457063477012903+9.40734203869213E-002i | 0.000911414 |
| 0.9000 | -0.504 | 90 | 17.61252446 | -0.401939026899766-3.82318024054948E-002i | 0.00078858 |
| 0.9100 | -0.45 | 91 | 17.80821918 | -0.25558274486654-6.18114199989203E-002i | 0.000513576 |
| 0.9200 | -0.458 | 92 | 18.00391389 | -0.198769059902799-5.67941326050739E-002i | 0.000403757 |
| 0.9300 | -0.523 | 93 | 18.19960861 | -9.53852009466001E-003-9.94636251704868E-002i | 0.000195156 |
| 0.9400 | -0.402 | 94 | 18.39530333 | 0.118108733560192+0.174798543633572i | 0.000412032 |
| 0.9500 | -0.509 | 95 | 18.59099804 | 0.160432037943916+0.453369992858463i | 0.000939294 |
| 0.9600 | -0.447 | 96 | 18.78669276 | 4.47208878848853E-002+0.125845924705548i | 0.000260851 |
| 0.9700 | -0.462 | 97 | 18.98238748 | -0.17915405379133+0.384195382993815i | 0.000827955 |
| 0.9800 | -0.522 | 98 | 19.17808219 | -0.372308771368194-2.34528788216604E-002i | 0.000728607 |
| 0.9900 | -0.401 | 99 | 19.37377691 | 7.52035605307099E-002-1.36890952288607E-002i | 0.000149296 |
| 1.0000 | -0.512 | 100 | 19.56947162 | -1.62976042411506-0.174785300615682i | 0.003201379 |

.
.
.
Table Cont'd

| Time (sec.) | Voltage (avg) | Counter | Freq. (Hz) | FFT (avg) | Amplitude (avg) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4.7500 | -0.439 | 475 | 92.95499022 | -0.980003621162715-1.72068507267302i | 0.003867564 |
| 4.7600 | -0.526 | 476 | 93.15068493 | -0.786799114041881-1.99599329978933i | 0.004190371 |
| 4.7700 | -0.394 | 477 | 93.34637965 | -0.485424402852159-2.06281583436469i | 0.004138988 |
| 4.7800 | -0.494 | 478 | 93.54207436 | -0.25161251834537-2.25525310623467i | 0.00443212 |
| 4.7900 | -0.479 | 479 | 93.73776908 | 0.114825551542379-2.30452647107527i | 0.004506612 |
| 4.8000 | -0.446 | 480 | 93.9334638 | 0.427036374279046-2.18627755520587i | 0.004350767 |
| 4.8100 | -0.525 | 481 | 94.12915851 | 0.700274984852997-1.98375634269126i | 0.004108845 |
| 4.8200 | -0.398 | 482 | 94.32485323 | 0.93042450630307-1.7589459119486i | 0.003886464 |
| 4.8300 | -0.492 | 483 | 94.52054795 | 1.04197490942793-1.49153138884349i | 0.003553602 |
| 4.8400 | -0.47 | 484 | 94.71624266 | 1.09431775695686-1.18413901721968i | 0.003149148 |
| 4.8500 | -0.45 | 485 | 94.91193738 | 1.07948700704761-0.877326776329368i | 0.002716877 |
| 4.8600 | -0.528 | 486 | 95.10763209 | 0.913697152631271-0.525795104052749i | 0.002058952 |
| 4.8700 | -0.4 | 487 | 95.30332681 | 0.637581694745876-0.27063188267849i | 0.001352815 |
| 4.8800 | -0.495 | 488 | 95.49902153 | 0.290088046498189-5.29223345462469E-002i | 0.00057593 |
| 4.8900 | -0.465 | 489 | 95.69471624 | -0.141753016604169+1.554039906583E-002i | 0.00027852 |
| 4.9000 | 0 | 490 | 95.89041096 | -0.600187211577812-3.42696351333574E-002i | 0.00117415 |
| 4.9100 | 0 | 491 | 96.08610568 | -1.08489578685386-0.185004760673409i | 0.002149525 |
| 4.9200 | 0 | 492 | 96.28180039 | -1.54872675438712-0.515919754555661i | 0.00318828 |
| 4.9300 | 0 | 493 | 96.47749511 | -1.97299978468321-0.960300569731027i | 0.004285721 |
| 4.9400 | 0 | 494 | 96.67318982 | -2.31824822704005-1.56731883117558i | 0.005465527 |
| 4.9500 | 0 | 495 | 96.86888454 | -2.48721204893404-2.29485333429037i | 0.006609698 |
| 4.9600 | 0 | 496 | 97.06457926 | -2.51483612661897-3.05848270837768i | 0.007733664 |
| 4.9700 | 0 | 497 | 97.26027397 | -2.37469986904871-3.92829794114825i | 0.008965402 |
| 4.9800 | 0 | 498 | 97.45596869 | -2.03711466482813-4.77308097389414i | 0.010135973 |
| 4.9900 | 0 | 499 | 97.65166341 | -1.51563676527921-5.57318532827965i | 0.011280468 |
| 5.0000 | 0 | 500 | 97.84735812 | -0.818067214278094-6.29386664644949i | 0.012396112 |
| 5.0100 | 0 | 501 | 98.04305284 | 0.12071213946791-6.9115695059186i | 0.013501218 |
| 5.0200 | 0 | 502 | 98.23874755 | 1.15340023381167-7.33229089156104i | 0.01449698 |
| 5.0300 | 0 | 503 | 98.43444227 | 2.37433650922015-7.59420275947099i | 0.015540468 |
| 5.0400 | 0 | 504 | 98.63013699 | 3.59291030204943-7.57742009618474i | 0.016379058 |
| 5.0500 | 0 | 505 | 98.8258317 | 4.83143342629601-7.37208937173923i | 0.017215271 |
| 5.0600 | 0 | 506 | 99.02152642 | 6.07955964718423-6.93019294202947i | 0.018005717 |
| 5.0700 | 0 | 507 | 99.21722114 | 7.2132466620188-6.22104757994946i | 0.018604206 |
| 5.0800 | 0 | 508 | 99.41291585 | 8.25681453333609-5.27235979553828i | 0.019133924 |
| 5.0900 | 0 | 509 | 99.60861057 | 9.15268494359242-4.03087189358123i | 0.019533161 |
| 5.1000 | 0 | 510 | 99.80430528 | 9.65075248625335-2.76041332464683i | 0.019605027 |
| 5.1100 | 0 | 511 | 100 | 10.1322200016599-1.6452578120291i | 0.020048688 |

Comment: What do you mean when you say you are taking average values at a 100 Hz rate. For Fourier Analysis you need to take the instantaneous values of the voltage at the time the sample is taken. Average values implies there is a time factor associated with each sample which will modify the Fourier Analysis.

Comment: This is a complicated subject. Nyquist applies, but also be aware that frequencies in your data above the Nyquist frequency will be aliased into your FFT as another frequency. You must remove these higher frequencies first. And you also may need to apply a window function such as Hamming before you perform the FFT. I recommend that you create some simulated data (start with sine waves) in Excel and put them through the FFT to gain more understanding. Note that without a window function, waves that are not an exact multiple of the sampling will have weird artifacts.

Comment: @Mattman944 are you talking about the amplitude(s) that are graphed beyond the Nyquist theorem (half of sampling rate)? If so I agree and plan to exclude this data from the graph all together.

Comment: @Barry The "avg" values are an average of 3 readings which are each 1ms apart. So at a sample rate of 100Hz (10ms apart), data is read at, for example: 1.010, 1.011, and 1.012. These 3 readings are then averaged and the result is saved as a single point with a timestamp of 1.010. Therefore the "second" reading would be at 1.020, 1.021, 1.022, these would be averaged and the result is saved with a single timestamp of 1.020

Answer (score 1):

The second half of the data output is not 50-100 Hz, it is a mirror of 0-50 Hz.

1. Higher frequencies must be excluded before the FFT. Or else you get aliasing, the frequency is folded back. In the second picture, 60 Hz input appears as 40 Hz!

I created an Excel table similar to yours, except for the input data, instead I am inputting one or two sine waves.

[image]

60 Hz input: 40 Hz output!
[image]

2. Depending on the accuracy required, you may need to *window* the input. It is a complicated subject, there are books written on this. Wikipedia is a good start. A Hamming window is a popular choice.

If you have a single frequency where the wave exactly fits, you get a nice sharp output spike.

[image]

If the wave doesn't fit exactly, the output spectrum is not sharp, it is wide. *Windowing* will help this.

[image]

Here are the equations used to create the sample inputs. A sine wave =  sin(2\$\pi\$ft), where f is the frequency and t is time.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this breakdown @Mattman944 So if the result of the FFT doesn't present itself as a "sharp" spike, does this mean there is too much noise or other, very similar, frequencies occurring? Or does it just imply a result with low confidence?

Comment: Whenever you measure a continous signal with a finite number of discrete samples there will be compromises. You need to understand the compromises and adjust your sampling method appropriately. When you put in a single frequency and get multiple frequencies out this is an example of the compromises.